# Python tab-completion not working in interactive console (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: python, terminal, ubuntu-20.04, tab-completion

In my `~/.bashrc` I have the following line to set the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc.py
```

Contents of ~/.pythonrc.py:

```
try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    print("Module readline not available.")
else:
    print("TAB-COMPLETE LOADED.")
    import rlcompleter
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
```

When running just

`python3`

in the terminal the message "TAB-COMPLETE LOADED" is printed and tab-complete works as expected on variables, however when running the following file via

`python3 example.py`

it doesn't work. The expected message is not printed and it just inserts a tab when pressing tab. It behaves the same regardless of whether the variable was declared in the console or the file.

example.py:

```
test_variable = 123
import code; code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals()))
```

I can't figure out why my `pythonrc.py` would be loaded for the former but not the latter. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround rather than an answer, but likely good enough for many.

Change example.py to:

```
import readline
import rlcompleter
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")

test_variable = 123
import code; code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals()))
```